# Отправка объекта WebSockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

На сервере есть объект

```
players = {};

players[1] = {
      x: 300,
      y: 300
    };
```

Нужно отправить его клиенту. С помощью модуля socket.io знаю как это делается, а на чистом ws не нашел каких-нибудь вариантов.

Может быть:

```
clients[1].send(players);
```

Но как в таком случае на стороне клиента получить и x: 300 и y: 300

Вот здесь получаю сообщение, а что дальше?

```
socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
//нужно вывести значения переданного объекта
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
   if(typeOf event.data === String ){
      //create a JSON object
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log(jsonObject);
      console.log(“Received data string”);

   }
}
```

Взято с:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/websockets_send_receive_messages.htm